# How to stop an rtmp stream using stop button of samsung blu ray device

Tags: actionscript-2, rtmp, samsung-smart-tv

im playing an rtmp stream using netConnection and netStream of flash as 2.0. The steam is playing fine on the above mentioned samsung device, now i want to stop the stream using the stop button of the device remote control but im facing problem in it. I used the 'UP' key and it worked fine but the stop button is not working.

I have used the flash.externalInterface.addcallback but no progress

Anyone worked in this direction me help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samsung stop button can be used in action script using the flash externalInterface class.
Using the addCallback function i communicated with javaScript and got the job done